# How to select 2 table with condition and show all data

Tags: mysql

How to select 2 table with condition and show all data

```
store_profile
id + store_name
1  | Accessorize.me 
2  | Active IT 
3  | Edushop
4  | Gift2Kids
5  | Heavyarm 
6  | Bamboo 

store_fee
id + store_id + date_end
1  |    1     | 27-6-2013
2  |    2     | 29-8-2013
3  |    3     | 02-6-2013
4  |    4     | 20-4-2013
```

Below is my previous query

```
$query = "select sp.id, sp.store_name, sf.id, sf.store_id, sf.date_end from store_profile sp, store_fee sf where sf.store_id=sp.id"
```

and the result is something like this :

```
1  | Accessorize.me  27-6-2013
2  | Active IT       29-8-2013
3  | Edushop         02-6-2013
4  | Gift2Kids       20-4-2013
```

but what i want is show all store name including `date_end` but if no `date_end` still can show store name with empty `date_end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an outer join.  With an outer join, columns on the joining table do not need to match the conditional columns in the joined table to get results:

```
SELECT * FROM store_profile sp LEFT JOIN store_fee sf ON (sf.store_id = sp.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join:

```
select sp.id, sp.store_name, sf.id, sf.store_id, sf.date_end 
from store_profile sp left join store_fee sf on sf.store_id=sp.id
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using is interpreted as `INNER JOIN`, which means that stores without a corresponding entry in `store_profile` won't show up. You want to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT sp.id, sp.store_name, sf.id, sf.store_id, sf.date_end 
FROM store_profile sp
LEFT JOIN store_fee sf 
ON sf.store_id=sp.id
```

`LEFT JOIN` means that all records in the first table will be returned, even if there's not a match in the second table.